# photoshop - export file simultaeously in multiple jpeg qualities or file formats

Tags: export, jpeg, photoshop

In photoshop I need to export files in both 100% and 10%. is there a simple way i can do this in one go instead of having to do this twice? thanks

Comment: Is this a coding question? If not, you shoukd probably ask on Graphic Design stack exchange

Comment: 10% what?? Are you talking about image size or jpeg quality?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're talking about jpeg quality.

With a bit of digging you can find a [function to save as an image as jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192763/skip-dialog-boxes-in-photoshop-script/61094997#61094997).

```js
// Path to the two images, named appropriately
// NOTE change to suit your needs
var myFileA = "C:\\myfolder\\myjpeg_high_quality.jpg";
var myFileB = "C:\\myfolder\\myjpeg_low_quality.jpg";

// Jpeg quality used to be from 1-10 in the old days.
// Now it's from 1-12, Let's save out the best and the worst.
jpeg_it(myFileA, 12);
jpeg_it(myFileB, 1);


// function JPEG IT (file path + file name, quality)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function jpeg_it(filePath, jpgQuality)
{
  if(! jpgQuality) jpgQuality = 12;

  // jpg file options
  var jpgFile = new File(filePath);
  jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
  jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
  jpgSaveOptions.quality = jpgQuality;

  activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```